# How to access the elements of a record in coq

Tags: coq

Suppose I have a record

```
Record ToyModel:={
universe:Set; 
aNiceProperty:universe->Prop;
color:universe->nat
}.
```

I would like to define a notion of compatibility for 
elements of type ToyModel.

```
Definition Compatible(T1 T2: ToyModel):=
if there is an element of T1.universe with color a then there 
exists an element of T2.universe with color a.
```

How can I write that in coq? The problem is that I don't know
how to access the elements inside a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields of the record become accessor functions for it, so it should just be a matter of:

```
universe t (* where t : ToyModel *)
color t u  (* where t : ToyModel, u : universe *)
```

Or:

```
t.(universe)
t.(color) u
```

You might have to:

```
Set Printing Projections.
```

cf. https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#toc15